# SQL Server 2008 : Decimal column in where clause decimal part effects query speed

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, database-performance

I have a decimal(15,10) column that contains the OLE Automation format of creation dates. And when you execute a query like

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE RECORDTIMEOA BETWEEN 41667 AND 41667.9999999999 --Decimal Part is 10 characters
```

the query returns all results in 8 or 9 secs. But instead of using 41667 integer value you use 41667.0000000000 then the query returns all results **under 1 second**. This is also happening when you put 9 or 8 characters in the second decimal part like

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE RECORDTIMEOA  BETWEEN 41667 AND 41667.99999999 --Decimal part is 8 characters
```

I have a nonclustered index on that column maybe it is effecting this issue, so i wonder what's the difference between below queries why first one returns in 8 secs and the others under 1 sec?

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE RECORDTIMEOA  BETWEEN 41667 AND 41667.9999999999
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE RECORDTIMEOA  BETWEEN 41667 AND 41667.9999999
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE RECORDTIMEOA  BETWEEN 41667.0000000000 AND 41667.9999999999
```

Please let me know if you can help..

UPDATE : I'm adding two execution plans for the queries

[image: This is the execution plan of slow query.]

[image: This is the execution plan of fast query.]

**UPDATE** : This is the execution plan after CAST method applied
[image: This is the execution plan after CAST method applied.]

Comment: Can you please post the query execution plan in both the cases ?

Comment: Ok, i've added both execution plans, first one is the slow one and the bottom one is fast one.

Comment: How does this perform? `SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE recordtimeoa >= Cast(41667 As decimal(15,10)) AND recordtimeoa < Cast(41668 As decimal(15,10))`

Comment: P.S. RID Lookup is the culprit. Read this article by Aaron Bertrand: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2195/identifying-key-and-rid-lookup-issues-and-how-to-resolve/ "...[RID] lookups occur when an index does not satisfy the query (non-covered query) and therefore additional data needs to be retrieved from the clustered index or the heap..."

Comment: yeah! it worked fine, but why this is happening?

Comment: I'm guessing that the integer values in your initial query are not being casted to the target type of decimal(15,10) but instead the column you are referencing is being converted to integer and as such the index cannot be used. You need to always be **explicit** with your data types.

Comment: if u use cast method then you may be take long time to large rows, how many rows are we talking about in here? Can you post your execution plan with cast metods applied?

Comment: @ramazanulucay the cast version is not casting the column values, it is casting the *literal* values to match the data type of the column.

Comment: yes, i've got some problems with large data sets, but the slow query runs fast this time, i'm really confused :D

Comment: i'm adding execution plan right now.

Comment: @ramazanulucay i've added the execution plan after cast applied.

Answer (score 0):

It could be there is a data conversion going on here that is preventing the index from being used. Your best bet is to look at the generated query plan from SSMS, for both queries, and see if a scan is being done on the slower query instead of a seek.

If both queries are doing a seek, then it's probably a case of caching. The rows (and query plan) are already in memory, cached, for the faster query.

Comment: both of queries are doing index seek, but the fast one seems %2 cost, slower one %91 cost of the query. I don't think there's a cache issue in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using Between function that is inclusive of lower and upper limit your could convert your where clause to use `>= and <` this would be a good test to check your performance and look over execution plan to understand how SQL server is using an index.

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE WHERE RECORDTIMEOA >= 41667 AND RECORDTIMEOA < 41668
```

Here is great post from [Turgay Sahtiyan blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/turgays/archive/2013/09/16/data-mismatch-on-where-clause-might-cause-serious-performance-problems.aspx) that talks about data type mismatches in `where` clause and what performance problem it causes. This following article lists all implicit and explicit conversions: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191530.aspx that take place.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but i've already tried that there's nothing changed and also if you put two integer like in your query it works fine (under 1 sec).

Comment: without seeing the XML data of execution plan for details, it is likely that you issue come from forcing SQL Server to find values with more precision that it is including in index. Thus when you only 7 decimal places it just jumps to correct spot versus using 10 decimal places and it is having to look at each value. What is maximum precision point that you actually have in your column?